# How does a balance on my credit card affect my credit score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score

How my score will change if I go from having no balance to one that uses less than 20% of my available credit? Will it be a drop of just a few points or 20+?

Answer (score 4):

Over the years I've seen similar questions come up and with an easy way to run a test, here's what I did.

I never carry a balance month to month, but learned that balances on one's accounts don't distinguish between paid in full each month vs an ongoing balance. e.g. New charges of $5,000 every month look the same as if one were paying $100/mo toward this debt and struggling to stay current. I got into the habit of paying in full before the statement was cut. This worked for a time, until one card statered to report the balance not at statement time, but at month end. So, a bill cut on the 15th, due on the 10th, was now getting paid in full on the 29th, along with all new charges made. This kept our (my wife and I share most accounts) scores in the 825-850 range depending on the method and bureau reporting. Now for the experiment -

Each year, in December, my yearend donations add to over $10,000. This gave me a chance for a controlled single ping to my credit report. I left $12K as a balance for 12/31 and paid it in January. Total usage was still only 13%, but the impact was a full 26 point drop. Nearly all of it was recovered as the end of January zero balance was reported and I expect it to tick up a few more points in the months to come.

[image]

This image, edited to get dates/score showing on one graphic, reflect what Credit Karma shows me as reports from TransUnion and Experion. Elsewhere, Synchrony, the bank Amazon store card uses for billing, gives me a VantageScore 4.0 as 844 with no impact at all from my experiment. A flat line for the past year.

In general, there's no benefit to the 820+ score vs anything above 800 or so. Articles I read use 740-750 at the line of "Excellent Credit" with some suggesting 800 or higher is "exceptional". Do your own research on this.  This answer is targeted towards those who are close to the next level, for whom a 20 point difference gets them from fair to good or good to excellent. Since credit utilization has no memory, it's wise to view scores before getting a new mortgage or car loan a few months ahead to see if it's worth the effort to improve the score a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler answer is: it depends.

The scoring models all use credit utilization as the metric for calculating the effect of carrying a balance.  The rule of thumb is to not use more than 25% (I prefer 20%) of your available credit - why?  Because using more than that might be an indicator you're using your credit cards to live beyond your income, and that's a red flag to any creditor.
So, if you have $10,000 available credit across all your cards, carrying a balance of $2,500 or less would have a fairly minimal effect on your score.

Keep in mind that as soon as you begin paying down your balance, any negative consequences to your score are recouped anyway.  Depending on your bank and how frequently it reports to the bureaus, you could see this effect pretty quickly.

As noted, there are almost daily variations in your credit score for a wide variety of reasons, so it can sometimes be very difficult to attribute how much of a score change is due to one specific factor.

If your score is in the middle of a range ("bad", "poor", "fair", "excellent", "exceptional") then I would highly doubt suddenly carrying a balance (unless it's a big balance) would have any meaningful effect on your score overall.  If you're in the market to buy a car, take out a mortgage, or some other kind of large loan then there's not much reason to be too concerned about how carrying a balance will affect your score.  After all, you only need to pay down that balance ahead of applying for a loan in order to get whatever points were lost as a result of that balance back.